# Putting a table into jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and quite frankly, I'm pretty bad at coding. 
I am making a website for a school assignment and I need to put a table in #btn4 the "tickets" Tab.

I have created the table on a different document, as was suggested to me. But when I try to put it into my code it doesn't work.

Either I have put it in the wrong area, or have made the table incorrectly.

Here is the code for the table:

```
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><p>Super Early Bird</p>
        <p>Ends Dec 23, 2018 </p></td>
      <td><p> Early Bird</p>
        <p>Ends Mar 3, 2019 </p></td>
      <td><p> Regular</p>
        <p>After Mar 3, 2019 </p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Conference</p>
        <p>The most popular option.</p>
        <p>(Price listed is per ticket) </p></td>
      <td>$599 </td>
      <td>$699 </td>
      <td>$799 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Conference- 4 Packs</p>
        <p>Buy 4 at once and SAVE.</p>
        <p>(Price listed is per ticket) </p></td>
      <td>$499</td>
      <td>$599 </td>
      <td>$699 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Freelancer</p>
        <p>A full 3 day conference ticket for thise who do not work full time for a single company or client </p></td>
      <td> $399</td>
      <td> $499</td>
      <td> $599</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Non-Profit/ Academic/ Military/&nbsp;Government Discount <br>
        <br>
      A full 3 day conference ticket that is discounted for those who work at an NFP, a school, or the government or military. *Proof of employment required.</td>
      <td>$499 </td>
      <td>$599 </td>
      <td>$699 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>The WORKS </p>
        <p>Includes the 3 day conference (April 29-May 1, 2019) plus the workshop day (April 28) </p></td>
      <td>$799 </td>
      <td>$899 </td>
     <td>$999 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>FITC EXCLUSIVE - </p>
        <p>New for 2019 </p>
        <p>• Very limited quantity</p>
        <p> • Access to Exclusive sessions</p>
        <p> • Invites to Exclusive Parties</p>
        <p> • Exclusive swag</p>
        <p> • Skip the line pass pickup </p>
        <p>• Extra drink tickets for evening events </p>
        <p>• Plus more exclusive perks to be revealed! </p></td>
      <td>$899 </td>
      <td> $999</td>
      <td> 1099</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>FLEX </p>
        <p>A transferable conference ticket. (April 29-May 1, 2019) </p></td>
      <td> $699</td>
      <td> $799</td>
      <td>$899 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>FLEX - 4 Pack Buy </p>
        <p>4 tickets and save. (Price listed is per ticket) </p></td>
      <td> $599</td>
      <td>$699 </td>
      <td>$799 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Workshop Only </p>
        <p>Access to one of our workshops (April 28). $199 $249 $349 </p></td>
      <td> $199</td>
      <td>$249 </td>
      <td>$349 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One Day Only <br>
Attend one day of FITC Toronto 2019. Includes access to all three evening events. </td>
      <td>n/a </td>
      <td> n/a</td>
      <td>$399 </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is my code for the website. I'm not sure where the issue is coming from so I will be including it all.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Set</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.clearfix {
    overflow: auto;
}

nav {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:#376b82;

}


.butters{
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    background-image:url(http://placehold.it/140x140);
    margin: 10px auto 5px auto;
    cursor:pointer;
}
    #btn1{
        background-image:url(a2Resources/icons4/speakers.png);

    }

    #btn2{
        background-image:url(a2Resources/icons4/locations.png);
    }
    #btn3{
        background-image:url(a2Resources/icons4/hotels.png);

    }
    #btn4{
        background-image:url(a2Resources/icons4/tickets.png);
    }
    #btn5{
        background-image:url(a2Resources/icons4/volunteer.png);
    }

#container{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#masthead{
    background-image:url("LCTC.svg");
    height:250px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    align-content: center;
}
#content{
    margin-left: 206px;
    padding:50px;
}
h2{
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="masthead">

</div>
<div class="clearfix">

<nav>
    <div class="butters" id="btn1"></div>
    <div class="butters" id="btn2"></div>
    <div class="butters" id="btn3"></div>
    <div class="butters" id="btn4"></div>
    <div class="butters" id="btn5"></div>

  </nav>

  <section id="content">
    <h2>Technology & Creativity Conference</h2>
      <p>

<b>Date: Sept 27-29, 2019</b>
          <br>
           <br>


<b>Where: Lethbridge, AB</b>
           <br>
          <br>

The fictitious Technology & Creative Conference is a globally recognized industry event showcasing the best the world has to offer in design, digital development, media and innovation in creative technologies – it’s three days and nights of presentations, parties, installations and performances that unite and transform the industry.
          <br>
          <br>

Our event explores the future of everything innovative, technical and creative to leave you informed, challenged and inspired. With hand-picked speakers from all over the world and from a variety of backgrounds; whether you’re after a highly focused experience, or your interests are more interdisciplinary, we’ve got you covered.
 <br>
          <br>
<b>Highlights</b>
          <br>
•   Over 70 presenters across three action-packed days and nights;
          <br>
•   Four inspiring tracks covering creativity, development, business, marketing, hardware, creative coding and more;
          <br>
•   Join an incredible group of talented, passionate people from around the world;
          <br>
•   Get hands-on with some of the latest hardware used in ways you’ve never even imagined in our exhibitor area;
           <br>
•   Kick-ass evening parties, performances and activities
    <br>
          <br>
           <br>

<b>Why Should You Attend?</b>
           <br>
          <br>
•   CREATIVES – From artists and illustrators, to filmmakers and animators, plus designers from UI to VFX, this conference will leave you full of ideas to bring back to your personal and professional work.
          <br>
•   TECHNOLOGISTS – Learn how to bring your most creative self into your code from some of the most exciting minds pushing technology forward. From techniques to toolkits to emerging platforms and wearables, you’ll walk away inspired by innovative solutions.
          <br>
•   EXECUTIVES / MARKETERS – Explore the future of innovation, technology, and creativity through presentations from cutting edge artists, studios, creatives, and technologists from around the world.
</p>
  </section>



</div>
</div><!--end container-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){


                $("#btn1").click(function(){
                        $("#content").slideUp("slow", function(){
                            $("#content").html("<h2>Speakers</h2><p>Speaker lineup will follow in late March. In the meantime, if you work or learn in one of the following areas, there will be talks of interest for you. <br> Catergories: <ul>Animator</ul><ul>Artist</ul><ul>Creative Code</ul><ul>Designer</ul><ul>Developer</ul><ul>Educator</ul><ul>Owner/Founder</ul><ul>Typography</ul><ul>UX/UI</ul><ul>VFX</ul><ul>Illustrator</ul><ul>Creative Technologist</ul><ul>Director</ul><ul>Photographer</ul><ul>Creative Director</ul><ul>Filmmaker</ul><ul>VR</ul><ul>Story Teller</ul><ul>Researcher</ul><ul>Futurist</ul><ul>AR</ul><ul>Marketing</ul><ul>Motion Designer</ul><ul>Producer</ul></p>")
                                .slideDown("slow");
                        });
                            });

            $("#btn2").click(function(){
                        $("#content").slideUp("slow", function(){
                            $("#content").html("<h2>Location</h2><p>The Venue is the oldest theatre in the downtown core and presents cutting-edge contemporary performing arts from around the world. <br> Imagine a space where we can come together to create and learn with others, where we can actively stage and build shared meaning and culture.The Venue is this place. <br>It is the space where art, ideas and people connect in new ways, where we can simultaneously be surprised by the imagination of strangers and be turned inside out by art. <br>Where we beckon each other towards aspiration. A vibrant meeting place for experiment, innovation and spontaneous interaction. Where people forge new relationships with each other, have new conversations and engage differently with diverse perspectives and experiences. <br>It will be a vital component in people’s lives and the life of the city and beyond. The Venue reflects how arts centres need to operate in order to challenge and shift social norms and inspire people to participate, reconnect and work towards positive change. <br>Immersive, experimental and experiential, a hothouse of creativity, exchange and connection, The Junction will be a rich and dynamic arena to explore our contemporary world.</p>")
                                .slideDown("slow");
                        });
                            });




                        $("#btn3").click(function(){
                        $("#content").slideUp("slow", function(){
                            $("#content").html("<h2>Hotels</h2><p><b>Official Host Hotel</b><br><br>The Downtown Hotel is the conference host hotel, and the best place for you to dive into a creative atmosphere! <br>With your stay, you’ll be minutes away from the subway, evening events, bars, restaurants. You may even bump into your favourite artist in the elevator, so start practicing your pitch! <br>The special conference rate is $215 CDN per night which includes complimentary WiFi. <br>Book your stay today by calling 1-800-ALL-FAKE. The group rate is valid until March 28. The hotel will sell out so make sure to book your room today! </p>")
                                .slideDown("slow");
                        });


                    //fancy content change  
                    });
                            $("#btn4").click(function(){
                        $("#content").slideUp("slow", function(){
                            $("#content").html("<h2>Tickets</h2>")
                                .slideDown("slow");
                        });
                            });

                    $("#btn5").click(function(){
                        $("#content").slideUp("slow", function(){
                            $("#content").html("<h2>Volunteer</h2><p>Thank you for your interest in our Volunteer Team. <br> If selected, you will be scheduled for a couple of shifts at the event in exchange for a FREE ticket to the conference. Please provide the information requested, including your availability during the event. <br> Volunteers will be scheduled for approximately one full-day or two half-day shifts during the event, so when you are filling out your availability, keep in mind this does not mean you will be scheduled for every shift you are available. </p>")
                                .slideDown("slow");
                        });
                            });
```

When I input the table into the code, this is how I'm doing it:

```
$("#btn4").click(function(){
                        $("#content").slideUp("slow", function(){
                            $("#content").html("<h2>Tickets</h2><table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><p>Super Early Bird</p>
        <p>Ends Dec 23, 2018 </p></td>
      <td><p> Early Bird</p>
        <p>Ends Mar 3, 2019 </p></td>
      <td><p> Regular</p>
        <p>After Mar 3, 2019 </p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Conference</p>
        <p>The most popular option.</p>
        <p>(Price listed is per ticket) </p></td>
      <td>$599 </td>
      <td>$699 </td>
      <td>$799 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Conference- 4 Packs</p>
        <p>Buy 4 at once and SAVE.</p>
        <p>(Price listed is per ticket) </p></td>
      <td>$499</td>
      <td>$599 </td>
      <td>$699 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Freelancer</p>
        <p>A full 3 day conference ticket for thise who do not work full time for a single company or client </p></td>
      <td> $399</td>
      <td> $499</td>
      <td> $599</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Non-Profit/ Academic/ Military/&nbsp;Government Discount <br>
        <br>
      A full 3 day conference ticket that is discounted for those who work at an NFP, a school, or the government or military. *Proof of employment required.</td>
      <td>$499 </td>
      <td>$599 </td>
      <td>$699 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>The WORKS </p>
        <p>Includes the 3 day conference (April 29-May 1, 2019) plus the workshop day (April 28) </p></td>
      <td>$799 </td>
      <td>$899 </td>
     <td>$999 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>FITC EXCLUSIVE - </p>
        <p>New for 2019 </p>
        <p>• Very limited quantity</p>
        <p> • Access to Exclusive sessions</p>
        <p> • Invites to Exclusive Parties</p>
        <p> • Exclusive swag</p>
        <p> • Skip the line pass pickup </p>
        <p>• Extra drink tickets for evening events </p>
        <p>• Plus more exclusive perks to be revealed! </p></td>
      <td>$899 </td>
      <td> $999</td>
      <td> 1099</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>FLEX </p>
        <p>A transferable conference ticket. (April 29-May 1, 2019) </p></td>
      <td> $699</td>
      <td> $799</td>
      <td>$899 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>FLEX - 4 Pack Buy </p>
        <p>4 tickets and save. (Price listed is per ticket) </p></td>
      <td> $599</td>
      <td>$699 </td>
      <td>$799 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Workshop Only </p>
        <p>Access to one of our workshops (April 28). $199 $249 $349 </p></td>
      <td> $199</td>
      <td>$249 </td>
      <td>$349 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One Day Only <br>
Attend one day of FITC Toronto 2019. Includes access to all three evening events. </td>
      <td>n/a </td>
      <td> n/a</td>
      <td>$399 </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>")
                                .slideDown("slow");
                        });
                            });
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: When I put the table in the code, as I do in the last example of my post, all of my code stops working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** see @BitwiseCreative more thorough solution below, which is how this should actually be handled for many reasons (browser support, code organization, debugging, SEO, pony unicorns .etc)

In JavaScript you can’t have multi-line Strings like that so you’ll either need to move  all of your HTML string onto one line or use [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) interpolation by enclosing your string in back-ticks ``` `` ```instead of quotes `””`...

```
$("#btn4").click(function(){
   $("#content").slideUp("slow", function(){
     $("#content").html(`<h2>Tickets</h2><table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><p>Super Early Bird</p>
        <p>Ends Dec 23, 2018 </p></td>
      <td><p> Early Bird</p>
        <p>Ends Mar 3, 2019 </p></td>
      <td><p> Regular</p>
        <p>After Mar 3, 2019 </p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Conference</p>
        <p>The most popular option.</p>
        <p>(Price listed is per ticket) </p></td>
      <td>$599 </td>
      <td>$699 </td>
      <td>$799 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Conference- 4 Packs</p>
        <p>Buy 4 at once and SAVE.</p>
        <p>(Price listed is per ticket) </p></td>
      <td>$499</td>
      <td>$599 </td>
      <td>$699 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Freelancer</p>
        <p>A full 3 day conference ticket for thise who do not work full time for a single company or client </p></td>
      <td> $399</td>
      <td> $499</td>
      <td> $599</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Non-Profit/ Academic/ Military/&nbsp;Government Discount <br>
        <br>
      A full 3 day conference ticket that is discounted for those who work at an NFP, a school, or the government or military. *Proof of employment required.</td>
      <td>$499 </td>
      <td>$599 </td>
      <td>$699 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>The WORKS </p>
        <p>Includes the 3 day conference (April 29-May 1, 2019) plus the workshop day (April 28) </p></td>
      <td>$799 </td>
      <td>$899 </td>
     <td>$999 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>FITC EXCLUSIVE - </p>
        <p>New for 2019 </p>
        <p>• Very limited quantity</p>
        <p> • Access to Exclusive sessions</p>
        <p> • Invites to Exclusive Parties</p>
        <p> • Exclusive swag</p>
        <p> • Skip the line pass pickup </p>
        <p>• Extra drink tickets for evening events </p>
        <p>• Plus more exclusive perks to be revealed! </p></td>
      <td>$899 </td>
      <td> $999</td>
      <td> 1099</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>FLEX </p>
        <p>A transferable conference ticket. (April 29-May 1, 2019) </p></td>
      <td> $699</td>
      <td> $799</td>
      <td>$899 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>FLEX - 4 Pack Buy </p>
        <p>4 tickets and save. (Price listed is per ticket) </p></td>
      <td> $599</td>
      <td>$699 </td>
      <td>$799 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Workshop Only </p>
        <p>Access to one of our workshops (April 28). $199 $249 $349 </p></td>
      <td> $199</td>
      <td>$249 </td>
      <td>$349 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One Day Only <br>
Attend one day of FITC Toronto 2019. Includes access to all three evening events. </td>
      <td>n/a </td>
      <td> n/a</td>
      <td>$399 </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>`)
                                .slideDown("slow");
                        });
                            });
```

Comment: Answers the question, yes. However, just a note, this doesn't work in IE (yeah, I know, who cares), is more difficult to work with (in my opinion), and won't be read as page content for SEO purposes.

Comment: No you’re absolutely right, I was being lazy, that should definitely be acknowledged. I’ll append some workarounds to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest leaving the HTML out of the JS. You can hide it by default, and control it with jQuery. Here's an example:

```js
$(function() {

  var curId = false;
  // Click Nav
  $('#nav li').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('show');
    if (curId === false) {
      $(id).slideDown('slow')
      curId = id;
    } else {
      if (id !== curId) {
        $(curId).slideUp('slow', function() {
          $(id).slideDown('slow');
        });
        curId = id;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#nav li {
  color: #f09;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li data-show="#table">Show Table</li>
    <li data-show="#list">Show List</li>
    <li data-show="#other-thing">Show Other Thing</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="table" style="display: none;">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>stuff in first col</td>
          <td>stuff in second col</td>
          <td>stuff in third col</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>stuff in first col</td>
          <td>stuff in second col</td>
          <td>stuff in third col</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>stuff in first col</td>
          <td>stuff in second col</td>
          <td>stuff in third col</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>stuff in first col</td>
          <td>stuff in second col</td>
          <td>stuff in third col</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>stuff in first col</td>
          <td>stuff in second col</td>
          <td>stuff in third col</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="list" style="display: none;">
    <ol>
      <li>Thing 1</li>
      <li>Thing 2</li>
      <li>Thing 3</li>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <div id="other-thing" style="display: none;">
    <pre>
                              /
                   __       //
                   -\= \=\ //
                 --=_\=---//=--
               -_==/  \/ //\/--
                ==/   /O   O\==--
   _ _ _ _     /_/    \  ]  /--
  /\ ( (- \    /       ] ] ]==-
 (\ _\_\_\-\__/     \  (,_,)--
(\_/                 \     \-
\/      /       (   ( \  ] /)
/      (         \   \_ \./ )
(       \         \      )  \
(       /\_ _ _ _ /---/ /\_  \
 \     / \     / ____/ /   \  \
  (   /   )   / /  /__ )   (  )
  (  )   / __/ '---`       / /
  \  /   \ \             _/ /
  ] ]     )_\_         /__\/
  /_\     ]___\
 (___)
</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you should do.

`all of my code stops working` . There should be an error. You can atleast check your console logs. You can use the inbuilt browser inspector console for  this (Try `F12` or `right-click and select inspect`). You can get an idea from that.

Since this is your first attempt to insert that table, try to insert it in small parts. Like just a one raw at a time. From this it will be easy for you to debug as well.

JavaScript actually support multiline Strings in ECMAScript 2015.
ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) introduces a new type of literal, namely [**template literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). They have many features, variable interpolation among others, but most importantly for this question, they can be multiline. **This can be used by you since you have quotation marks in the actual table element string**.

A template literal is delimited by backticks:

```
var html = `
   <div>
       <span>Your text here</span>
   </div>
`;
```

Without using [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to set the new elements, you can also use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) as well.